# Prove an identity for an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Prove that identity $\langle u,v\rangle = \text{Re}\langle v,u \rangle - i\text{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle $ Where $V$ is an inner product over $\mathbb{C}$.

I tried to use the common properties of inner product, but couldn't get much farther.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\mathrm{Re}\langle v,u\rangle= \mathrm{Re}\langle u,v\rangle$$
Also,
$$\langle v,iu\rangle=-i \langle v,u\rangle$$
And
$$\mathrm{Im}\langle v,u\rangle=- \mathrm{Im}\langle u,v\rangle$$
Hence when we multiply by $-i$ we are squaring the $-i$ that appears from conjugating by switching the order, obtaining the negative of the imaginary part of the original as the real part. Hence
$$\mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle=- \mathrm{Im}\langle u,v\rangle$$
This proves the identity.

For a less wordy derivation, note that for any complex number $z$,
$$\mathrm{Re}\ -iz=\mathrm{Im}\ z$$
So
$$\mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle= \mathrm{Re}-i\langle v,u\rangle= \mathrm{Im}\langle v,u\rangle=-\mathrm{Im}\langle u,v\rangle$$

Comment: @AlonAlon you're welcome.

Comment: Why is taking the $i$ "out" adds a minus sign?

Comment: @AlonAlon the inner product is conjugate-linear in the second argument. Conjugating $i$ gives $-i$.

Comment: And why is the third identity true? (sorry, I am beginner)

Comment: @AlonAlon that follows for the same reason. Since it's conjugate linear in the second argument, switching the order of the two vectors gives you the complex conjugate of what you started with.

Comment: Matt, could you show the last implication algebrically? I mean, If I start by: $\mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle  = \mathrm{Re}\left(-i\langle v,u\rangle\right)$ how should I continue?

Comment: @AlonAlon please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Start from the right side and use $Re(z) = \frac 12 (z+\overline z)$.