# Why is $ \mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle=- \mathrm{Im}\langle u,v\rangle$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Why is this identity true?

$$\mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle=- \mathrm{Im}\langle u,v\rangle$$

If we start from LHS:

$$\mathrm{Re}\langle v,iu\rangle  = \mathrm{Re}\left(-i\langle v,u\rangle\right)$$

How to proceed? I can't just take the $-i$ out of the $\mathrm{Re}$ function

Comment: Isn't it better to clarify details in your original post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090601/prove-an-identity-for-an-inner-product

Comment: I thought it may be proper to open a new question about it.

Comment: If you have a complex number $z = {\rm Re}\, z + i \, {\rm Im}\, z $ and you multiply it by $-i$, how the real part of $-iz$ can be written in terms of ${\rm Re} \, z $ and ${\rm Im} \, z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$
u=\Re u + i \Im u, \quad v = \Re v + i \Im v,
$$
and
$$
\langle v,u \rangle = v \overline{u},
$$
we have that
$$
\Re \langle v,iu \rangle = \Re (-i \langle v,u \rangle) = \Re (-i v \overline{u})=\Re(-i (\Re v + i \Im v)(\Re u -i \Im u)).
$$
Now expand and compare.

But, as suggested in the comments, there is a quicker answer. Call $z = \langle v,u\rangle$, and notice that multiplication by $-i$ is just a rotation of $-\pi/2$ in the complex plane. This rotation turns the real part into the imaginary part, and since $\langle u,v \rangle = \overline{z}$, you get the negative sign.

Comment: $-i$ turns the real part into the positive imaginary part. It becomes negative when you switch the order of the factors in the inner product.

Comment: I've edited my answer, thank you.